# Kotlin `this` not returning correct instance in inherited class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two classes. One is the parent of the other. I'm instantiating an obect of HashMap inside of Foo, and trying to access that object, but in class Bar, I'm getting a reference on to `presenter as Map` not `presenter as HashMap` so none of my HashMap method calls are working.

I've read the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) and from that tried specifying `this.presenter` inside of `init{...}` like in Java, but I still can't seem to access the HashMap<> from inside of the child class.

```
open class Foo {
    var presenter = Map<>

    init {
        presenter = HashMap<>
    }

}

open class Bar : Foo() {
     //this is trying to call .put on the Map interface, so I get an error
     presenter.put(someData)

}
```

Comment: You would get the same result in another method in `Foo` as well.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the type as a `MutableMap`, also specify types of your Map:

```
open class Foo<K,V> {
    val presenter: MutableMap<K,V> = HashMap()
}
open class Bar : Foo<String,String>() {
    //this is trying to call .put on the Map interface, so I get an error
   fun doit(){
        presenter.put("","")
   }

}
```

You let the compiler infer the type of your `presenter`, which is a readonly map that does not have a `put`.

Comment: that makes sense. What about for custom classes that I want to assign inside the init? Do I have to consciously make a mutable implementation of that?

Comment: No this is only necessary if you use collections and maps because Kotlin encourages read only implementations